# Determining the price of a mystery box which can output differently weighted items with different prices

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

So I'm not sure if this is even possible, however I was hopeful someone here might be able to assist me in answering this question or at least guide me in the right direction... or let me know if I'm wasting my time on something which is impossible to solve.

Imagine you have a problem where you have a mystery box which when opened, will output a
randomly selected item with a given value. I'll create an example distribution:

Item A: 5% chance of dropping with $1000 value

Item B: 15% chance of dropping with $100 value

Item C: 30% chance of dropping with $1 value

Item D: 50% chance of dropping with $0.10 value

Based on these probabilities and the given prices, is it possible to determine the intrinsic value of the mystery box? In other words, what is the ideal price which, if you opened a sufficiently large number of the boxes for a given price, you will breakeven (assuming no other costs of transacting)?

If you need me to reword anything, please let me know and I will do so. Thanks!

EDIT: I completely forgot to mention one important part to this problem: what does this math look like if the price of these items can change randomly? Would I need to incorporate some sort of stochastic process in order to properly price the box?

Comment: What do you mean the price of an item can change randomly? Do you mean it comes out worth $\$1000$ but five minutes later it randomly becomes worth $\$200$, do you mean the distribution of items is as described above if you open it today but if you wait until tomorrow it will be replaced by a different randomly chosen distribution, or something else? What do you know about this additional randomness?

Comment: What I mean is that these items which are dropped from the box have a marketplace on which they're sold and can therefore fluctuate in price similar to that of a share in a company. The probabilities of the drop rates remain the same, however the price can change in a random fashion. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

Let $v_k$ be the value of item $k$ and let $p_k$ be the probability of that item being selected, then the breakeven value of the box is $\sum_k v_kp_k$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Building off of this, what would the math look like if I wanted to take into account that the items could change in price randomly? Would I need to incorporate some sort of stochastic process to make it valid? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Making the item value a random variable would lead to replacing $v_k$ by $E(v_k)$ in  the expression.  If you don't know the value of $E(v_k)$, there doesn't appear to be anything you do, except guess at a value.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the expected value, multiply each probability by the corresponding value, and then add up these four resulting products:
$$
0.05 \cdot \$1000 + 0.15 \cdot \$100 + 0.30 \cdot \$1 + 0.50 \cdot \$0.10
= \$50 + \$15 + \$0.30 + \$0.05 = \$65.35
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! How would it be different if I wanted to take into account that the items could change in price randomly? Would I need to incorporate some sort of stochastic process to make it valid? Thank you so much!!